# Error: unknown register when building uClinux

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, nios, uclinux

I'm trying to build uClinux according to the [instructions](http://alterawiki.com/wiki/InstallNios2Linux). I have a build problem that I don't understand.

```
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S: Assembler messages:
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:138: Error: expecting control register
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:138: Error: unknown register r5
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:546: Error: expecting control register
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:546: Error: unknown register r6
```

What should I do about it? The file `entry.S`

```
/*
 * linux/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2009, Wind River Systems Inc
 * Implemented by fredrik.markstrom@gmail.com and ivarholmqvist@gmail.com
 *
 * Based on:
 *
 * linux/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S  
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1999-2002, Greg Ungerer (gerg@snapgear.com)
 *  Copyright (C) 1998  D. Jeff Dionne <jeff@lineo.ca>,
 *                      Kenneth Albanowski <kjahds@kjahds.com>,
 *  Copyright (C) 2000  Lineo Inc. (www.lineo.com)
 *  Copyright (C) 2004  Microtronix Datacom Ltd.
 *
 * Based on:
 *
 *  linux/arch/m68knommu/kernel/entry.S
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1991, 1992  Linus Torvalds
 *
 * This file is subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public
 * License.  See the file README.legal in the main directory of this archive
 * for more details.
 *
 * Linux/m68k support by Hamish Macdonald
 *
 * 68060 fixes by Jesper Skov
 * ColdFire support by Greg Ungerer (gerg@snapgear.com)
 * 5307 fixes by David W. Miller
 * linux 2.4 support David McCullough <davidm@snapgear.com>
 */

#include <linux/sys.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <asm/asm-offsets.h>
#include <asm/asm-macros.h>
#include <asm/thread_info.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>
#include <asm/setup.h>
#include <asm/entry.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <asm/processor.h>

.macro GET_THREAD_INFO reg
.if THREAD_SIZE & 0xffff0000
    andhi   \reg, sp, %hi(~(THREAD_SIZE-1))
.else
    addi    \reg, r0, %lo(~(THREAD_SIZE-1))
    and \reg, \reg, sp
.endif
.endm

/* FIXME: Lots of these exceptions need to be handled */
.section .rodata
.align 4
exception_table:
    .word unhandled_exception   /* 0 - Reset */
    .word unhandled_exception   /* 1 - Processor-only Reset */
    .word external_interrupt    /* 2 - Interrupt */
    .word handle_trap       /* 3 - Trap Instruction */

    .word instruction_trap      /* 4 - Unimplemented instruction */
    .word handle_illegal        /* 5 - Illegal instruction */
    .word handle_unaligned      /* 6 - Misaligned data access */
    .word handle_unaligned      /* 7 - Misaligned destination address */

    .word handle_diverror       /* 8 - Division error */
    .word protection_exception_ba   /* 9 - Supervisor-only instr. address */
    .word protection_exception_instr /* 10 - Supervisor only instruction */
    .word protection_exception_ba   /* 11 - Supervisor only data address */

    .word unhandled_exception   /* 12 - Double TLB miss (data) */
    .word protection_exception_pte  /* 13 - TLB permission violation (x) */
    .word protection_exception_pte  /* 14 - TLB permission violation (r) */
    .word protection_exception_pte  /* 15 - TLB permission violation (w) */

    .word unhandled_exception   /* 16 - MPU region violation */

trap_table:
    .word   handle_system_call  // 0 
    .word   instruction_trap    // 1
    .word   instruction_trap    // 2
    .word   instruction_trap    // 3
    .word   instruction_trap    // 4
    .word   instruction_trap    // 5
    .word   instruction_trap    // 6
    .word   instruction_trap    // 7
    .word   instruction_trap    // 8
    .word   instruction_trap    // 9
    .word   instruction_trap    // 10
    .word   instruction_trap    // 11
    .word   instruction_trap    // 12
    .word   instruction_trap    // 13
    .word   instruction_trap    // 14
    .word   instruction_trap    // 15
    .word   instruction_trap    // 16
    .word   instruction_trap    // 17
    .word   instruction_trap    // 18
    .word   instruction_trap    // 19
    .word   instruction_trap    // 20
    .word   instruction_trap    // 21
    .word   instruction_trap    // 22
    .word   instruction_trap    // 23
    .word   instruction_trap    // 24
    .word   instruction_trap    // 25
    .word   instruction_trap    // 26
    .word   instruction_trap    // 27
    .word   instruction_trap    // 28
    .word   instruction_trap    // 29
#ifdef CONFIG_KGDB
    .word   handle_kgdb_breakpoint  /* 30 KGDB breakpoint */
#else
    .word   instruction_trap    // 30
#endif
    .word   handle_breakpoint   // 31

.text
.set noat
.set nobreak

ENTRY(inthandler)
    SAVE_ALL
    /* Clear EH bit before we get a new excpetion in the kernel
     * and after we have saved it to the exception frame. This is done
     * wheter it's trap, tlb-miss or interrupt. If we don't do this
     * estatus is not updated the next exception.
     */ 
    rdctl   r24,status
    movi    r9,-5
    and r24,r24,r9
    wrctl   status,r24

    /* Read cause and vector and branch to the associated handler (
         */
    mov r4,sp
        rdctl   r5,exception
        movia   r9,exception_table
        add     r24,r9,r5
        ldw     r24,0(r24)
        jmp     r24


/***********************************************************************
 * Handle traps
 ***********************************************************************
 */
ENTRY(handle_trap)
    ldw r24,-4(ea)  // instruction that caused the exception
    srli    r24,r24,4
    andi    r24,r24,0x7c
    movia   r9,trap_table
    add r24,r24,r9
    ldw r24,0(r24)
    jmp r24


/***********************************************************************
 * Handle system calls
 ***********************************************************************
 */
ENTRY(handle_system_call)
    /* Enable interrupts
     */
    rdctl   r10,status      
    ori r10,r10,0x0001
    wrctl   status,r10

    /* Reload registers destroyed by common code.
     */
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)

    /* Check that the requested system call is within limits
     */
    movui   r1,NR_syscalls
    bgeu    r2,r1,ret_invsyscall
    slli    r1,r2,2
    movhi   r11,%hiadj(sys_call_table)
    add r1,r1,r11
    ldw r1,%lo(sys_call_table)(r1)
    beq r1,r0,ret_invsyscall

    /* Get thread info pointer
     */
    movi    r11,%lo(0xfffff000) 
    and r11,sp,r11
    ldw r11,TI_FLAGS(r11)

    /* If someone is ptrace:ing us, take the long way.
     */
    BTBNZ   r11,r11,TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE,traced_system_call
#if 0
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r9,r8
    mov r8,r7
    mov r6,r5
    mov r5,r4
    mov r4,r2
    call    print_syscall
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ldw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)
    ldw r6,PT_R6(sp)
    ldw r7,PT_R7(sp)
    ldw r8,PT_R8(sp)
    ldw r9,PT_R9(sp)
#endif


    /* Execute the system call
     */
    callr   r1

    /* If the syscall returns a negative result:
     *   Set r7 to 1 to indicate error,
     *   Negate r2 to get a positive error code
     * If the syscall returns zero or a positive value:
     *   Set r7 to 0.
     * The sigreturn system calls will skip the code below by
     * adding to register ra. To avoid destroying registers
     * 
     * FIXME: We probably need an orig_r7
     */
translate_rc_and_ret:
    movi    r1,0
    bge r2,zero,3f
    sub r2,zero,r2
    movi    r1,1
3:  
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    stw r1,PT_R7(sp)
end_translate_rc_and_ret:

#if 0
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r4,r2
    mov r5,r1
    call    print_syscall_ret
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
#endif

ret_from_exception:
    ldw r1,PT_ESTATUS(sp)
    TSTBNZ  r1,r1,ESTATUS_EU,Luser_return   /* if so, skip resched, signals */

restore_all:
    rdctl   r10,status          /* disable intrs */
    andi    r10,r10,0xfffe
    wrctl   status, r10
    RESTORE_ALL
    eret

    /* If the syscall number was invalid return ENOSYS
    */
ret_invsyscall:
    movi    r2,-ENOSYS
    br translate_rc_and_ret


    /* This implements the same as above, except it calls
     * syscall_trace before and after the syscall in order
     * for utilities like strace and gdb to work.
     */
traced_system_call:
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    syscall_trace
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK

    /* r2 and r7-r9 might be destroyed  by syscall_trace and we need to restore
     * them before calling our syscall.
     */
    ldw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)
    ldw r6,PT_R6(sp)
    ldw r7,PT_R7(sp)
    ldw r8,PT_R8(sp)
    ldw r9,PT_R9(sp)

    /* Fetch the syscall function, we don't need to check the boundaries
     * since this is already done.
     */
    slli    r1,r2,2
    movhi   r11,%hiadj(sys_call_table)
    add r1,r1,r11
    ldw r1,%lo(sys_call_table)(r1)

    callr   r1

    /* If the syscall returns a negative result:
     *   Set r7 to 1 to indicate error,
     *   Negate r2 to get a positive error code
     * If the syscall returns zero or a positive value:
     *   Set r7 to 0.
     * The sigreturn system calls will skip the code below by
     * adding to register ra. To avoid destroying registers
     * 
     * FIXME: We probably need an orig_r7
     */
translate_rc_and_ret2:
    movi    r1,0
    bge r2,zero,4f
    sub r2,zero,r2
    movi    r1,1
4:  
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    stw r1,PT_R7(sp)
end_translate_rc_and_ret2:
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    syscall_trace
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    br ret_from_exception

Luser_return:
    GET_THREAD_INFO r11         /* get thread_info pointer */
    ldw r10,TI_FLAGS(r11)       /* get thread_info->flags */
    ANDI32  r11,r10,_TIF_WORK_MASK
    beq r11,r0,restore_all      /* Nothing to do */
    BTBZ    r1,r10,TIF_NEED_RESCHED,Lsignal_return

Lwork_resched:
    call    schedule
    br  ret_from_exception

Lsignal_return:
    BTBZ    r1,r10,TIF_SIGPENDING,restore_all
    mov r5,sp           /* pt_regs */
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r4,r0           /* oldset = 0 */
    movi    r6,1            /* syscall */
    call    do_signal
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    br  restore_all



/***********************************************************************
 * Handle external interrupts.
 ***********************************************************************
 */
/*
 * This is the generic interrupt handler (for all hardware interrupt
 * sources). It figures out the vector number and calls the appropriate
 * interrupt service routine directly.
 */
external_interrupt:
    rdctl   r12,ipending
    rdctl   r9,ienable
    and r12,r12,r9
    /* skip if no interrupt is pending */
    beq r12,r0,ret_from_interrupt

    movi    r24,-1
    stw r24,PT_ORIG_R2(sp)

    /*
     * Process an external hardware interrupt.
     */

    addi    ea,ea,-4        /* re-issue the interrupted instruction */
    stw ea,PT_EA(sp)
2:  movi    r4,%lo(-1)      /* Start from bit position 0, highest priority */
                    /* This is the IRQ # for handler call */
1:  andi    r10,r12,1       /* Isolate bit we are interested in */
    srli    r12,r12,1       /* shift count is costly without hardware multiplier */
    addi    r4,r4,1
    beq r10,r0,1b
    mov r5,sp           /* Setup pt_regs pointer for handler call */
    call    do_IRQ
    rdctl   r12,ipending        /* check again if irq still pending */
    rdctl   r9,ienable      /* Isolate possible interrupts */
    and r12,r12,r9
    bne r12,r0,2b
    /* br   ret_from_interrupt */   /* fall throught to ret_from_interrupt */

ENTRY(ret_from_interrupt)
    ldw r1,PT_ESTATUS(sp)   /* check if returning to kernel */
    TSTBNZ  r1,r1,ESTATUS_EU,Luser_return

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT
    GET_THREAD_INFO r1
    ldw r4,TI_PREEMPT_COUNT(r1)
    bne r4,r0,restore_all

need_resched:
    ldw r4,TI_FLAGS(r1)     // ? Need resched set
    BTBZ    r10,r4,TIF_NEED_RESCHED,restore_all
    ldw r4,PT_ESTATUS(sp)   // ? Interrupts off
    andi    r10,r4,STATUS_PIE
    beq r10,r0,restore_all
    movia   r4,PREEMPT_ACTIVE
    stw r4,TI_PREEMPT_COUNT(r1)
    rdctl   r10,status      /* enable intrs again */
    ori r10,r10,0x0001
    wrctl   status,r10
    PUSH    r1
    call    schedule
    POP r1
    mov r4,r0
    stw r4,TI_PREEMPT_COUNT(r1)
    rdctl   r10,status      /* disable intrs */
    andi    r10,r10,0xfffe
    wrctl   status, r10
    br  need_resched
#else
    br  restore_all
#endif

/***********************************************************************
 * Syscalls implemented in assembly
 ***********************************************************************
 */

ENTRY(sys_nios2cmpxchg)

    // r4 pointer to exchange variable
    // r5 old value
    // r6 new value
    // r8 - old interrupt status (assert this to enabled?)
    // r9 - temp
    // Disable interrupts (keep old status in r8)
        rdctl   r8,status
        andi    r9,r8,0xfffe
        wrctl   status,r9

    // Make sure we skip the r2/r7 translation code when we return.
        addi    ra,ra,(end_translate_rc_and_ret-translate_rc_and_ret)

ldw1:   ldw     r2, 0(r4)
        bne     r2, r5, .L6

    // We had a match, store the new value
stw1:   stw     r6, 0(r4)
.L6:
    // Reenable interrupts
        wrctl   status,r8

    // Store return value
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    // Indicate everything is ok
    movi    r2,0
    stw r2,PT_R7(sp)
        ret
fault:
        movi    r2,EFAULT
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    movi    r2,1
    stw r2,PT_R7(sp)
        wrctl   status,r8
        ret

    // setup the exception table
    .section __ex_table,"a"
        .word ldw1, fault
    .word stw1, fault
        .previous



/***********************************************************************
 * A few syscall wrappers
 ***********************************************************************
 */

ENTRY(sys_fork)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_fork
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_vfork)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_vfork
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_execve)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_execve
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_clone)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_clone
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_sigsuspend)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_sigsuspend
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_rt_sigsuspend)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_rt_sigsuspend
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_sigreturn)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_sigreturn
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    addi    ra,ra,(end_translate_rc_and_ret-translate_rc_and_ret)
    ret

ENTRY(sys_sigaltstack)
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)
    ldw r6,PT_SP(sp)
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_sigaltstack
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_rt_sigreturn)
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r4,sp
    call    do_rt_sigreturn
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    addi    ra,ra,(end_translate_rc_and_ret-translate_rc_and_ret)
    ret

/***********************************************************************
 * A few other wrappers and stubs
 ***********************************************************************
 */
protection_exception_pte:
    rdctl r6,pteaddr
    slli r6,r6,10
    call do_page_fault
    br ret_from_exception

protection_exception_ba:
    rdctl r6,badaddr
    call do_page_fault
    br ret_from_exception

protection_exception_instr:
    call handle_supervisor_instr
    br ret_from_exception

handle_breakpoint:
    call breakpoint_c
    br ret_from_exception

#ifdef CONFIG_ALIGNMENT_TRAP
handle_unaligned:
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call handle_unaligned_c
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    br ret_from_exception
#else
handle_unaligned:
    call handle_unaligned_c
    br ret_from_exception
#endif

handle_illegal:
    call handle_illegal_c
    br ret_from_exception

handle_diverror:
    call handle_diverror_c
    br ret_from_exception

#ifdef CONFIG_KGDB
handle_kgdb_breakpoint:
    call kgdb_breakpoint_c
    br ret_from_exception
#endif

/*
 * Beware - when entering resume, prev (the current task) is
 * in r4, next (the new task) is in r5, don't change these
 * registers.
 */
ENTRY(resume)

    rdctl   r7,status           /* save thread status reg */
    stw r7,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KPSR(r4)  

    andi    r7,r7,0x0fffe           /* disable interrupts */
    wrctl   status,r7

    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    stw sp,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KSP(r4)   /* save kernel stack pointer */
    ldw sp,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KSP(r5)   /* restore new thread stack */
    movia   r24,_current_thread     /* save thread */
    GET_THREAD_INFO r1
    stw r1,0(r24)
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK

    ldw r7,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KPSR(r5)  /* restore thread status reg */
    wrctl   status,r7
    ret

ENTRY(ret_from_fork)
    call    schedule_tail
    br  ret_from_exception
```

Recompiling with flags gives us:

```
    $ setarch i386 make -j1 V=1make -f tools/autotools.mk autotools-cache
   ...

  /bin/bash /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/checksyscalls.sh nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,./.missing-syscalls.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/. -I. -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -pipe -D__linux__ -D__ELF__ -mhw-mul -mno-hw-mulx -mhw-div -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -DUTS_SYSNAME=\"Linux\" -fno-builtin -G 0 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(missing_syscalls)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(missing_syscalls)" 
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=init
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=usr
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/nios2/kernel
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/nios2/mm
/bin/bash /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/gen_initramfs_list.sh -l -d > usr/.initramfs_data.cpio.d
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/nios2/platform
(cat /dev/null; ) > usr/modules.order
  nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,arch/nios2/kernel/.entry.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -D__ASSEMBLY__   -c -o arch/nios2/kernel/entry.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S
/bin/bash /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/mkcompile_h include/generated/compile.h \
    "nios2" "" "" "nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -pipe -D__linux__ -D__ELF__  -mhw-mul -mno-hw-mulx -mhw-div  -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -DUTS_SYSNAME=\"Linux\" -fno-builtin -G 0   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement   "
  /bin/bash /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/gen_initramfs_list.sh -o usr/initramfs_data.cpio   -d
(cat /dev/null; ) > init/modules.order
  nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,arch/nios2/kernel/.ptrace.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel -Iarch/nios2/kernel -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -pipe -D__linux__ -D__ELF__ -mhw-mul -mno-hw-mulx -mhw-div -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -DUTS_SYSNAME=\"Linux\" -fno-builtin -G 0 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(ptrace)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(ptrace)" -c -o arch/nios2/kernel/ptrace.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/ptrace.c
  nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,arch/nios2/kernel/.setup.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel -Iarch/nios2/kernel -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -pipe -D__linux__ -D__ELF__ -mhw-mul -mno-hw-mulx -mhw-div -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -DUTS_SYSNAME=\"Linux\" -fno-builtin -G 0 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(setup)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(setup)" -c -o arch/nios2/kernel/setup.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/setup.c
  nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,arch/nios2/kernel/.signal.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel -Iarch/nios2/kernel -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -pipe -D__linux__ -D__ELF__ -mhw-mul -mno-hw-mulx -mhw-div -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -DUTS_SYSNAME=\"Linux\" -fno-builtin -G 0 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(signal)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(signal)" -c -o arch/nios2/kernel/signal.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/signal.c
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S: Assembler messages:
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:138: Error: expecting control register
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:138: Error: unknown register r5
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:546: Error: expecting control register
/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S:546: Error: unknown register r6
(cat /dev/null; ) > arch/nios2/mm/modules.order
make[3]: *** [arch/nios2/kernel/entry.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/nios2/boot
make -f /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/scripts/Makefile.build obj=kernel
(cat /dev/null; ) > arch/nios2/platform/modules.order
(cat /dev/null; ) > arch/nios2/boot/modules.order
  /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist/linux-2.6.x/scripts/dtc/dtc -O dtb -o arch/nios2/boot/system.dtb -b 0  -d arch/nios2/boot/.system.dtb.d /home/developer/Downloads/nios.dts
DTC: dts->dtb  on file "/home/developer/Downloads/nios.dts"
  nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,arch/nios2/boot/.linked_dtb.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -D__ASSEMBLY__   -c -o arch/nios2/boot/linked_dtb.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/boot/linked_dtb.S
make[2]: *** [arch/nios2/kernel] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,usr/.initramfs_data.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -D__ASSEMBLY__ -DINITRAMFS_IMAGE="usr/initramfs_data.cpio"   -c -o usr/initramfs_data.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/usr/initramfs_data.S
   nios2-linux-gnu-ld  -mnios2elf   -r -o arch/nios2/boot/built-in.o arch/nios2/boot/linked_dtb.o 
   nios2-linux-gnu-ld  -mnios2elf   -r -o usr/built-in.o usr/initramfs_data.o 
make[2]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6'
make: *** [linux] Error 1
```

Comment: What is your gcc & binutils? Are you using exactly same versions of source as in your instructions? Can you post more details about steps done and failed step, also show entry.S file and how the assembler was started to get these error. Why so old instructions? There is bit newer here: https://rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/NiosIILinuxUserManual

Comment: @osgx I build for Cyclone IV. I can try the newer but they might not be for Cyclone IV (Altera DE2-115). I'll add more details. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Dj, this is just software. It will work if you can translate compatible nios2 softcore for your FPGA. What is linux version and where can I see the entry.S? This may look like **wrong assembler used** (incorrect settings of your environment) as nios always has r5 & r6: https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii5v1.pdf#page=49.

Comment: @osgx My gcc is the cross-compiler that I downloaded to make the build. It's called `nios2-linux-uclibc-gcc`

Comment: Dj, just `entry.S` is not enough. What was the full command line which failed (rerun make of linux kernel with `make -j1 V=1` for "verbose build").

Comment: Can you rerun `nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,arch/nios2/kernel/.entry.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/include -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/include -Iarch/nios2/include/generated -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include -include /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -D__ASSEMBLY__   -c -o arch/nios2/kernel/entry.o /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S` from right path with `-v` added to see which asm was used?

Comment: @osgx I keep getting `No such file or directory` and nothing is possible.

Comment: I try the verbose build and it just says `make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2`and then nothing is possible.

Comment: Before getting "`No such file or directory`" try to `cd` into right path `arch/nios2/kernel/`. And if you have "`make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2`", try to reproduce full build again (in other directory or with `make clean`). If problem can't be reproduced, the question is offtopic.

Comment: @osgx There is still an error any way I try. And yes, the errors are reproducible from a clean checkout. And yes, the errors appear in the right path. No matter how I do there will be build error.

Comment: @DjDac Did you checkout the `test-nios2` branch or the default branch from git?

Comment: @ceilingcat I tried both. Now I installed latest version of fedora and tried with that instead, getting a new different build error. The new build error seems better because it is a compiler error with C clearly stating which row it is instead of an assmebly error.

Comment: Dj, where did you get your "nios2-linux-gnu-gcc", what is exact version of the toolchain?

Comment: @osgx `$ nios2-linux-gnu-gcc -v
Reading specs from /opt/nios2/lib/gcc/nios2-linux-uclibc/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: /root/buildroot/toolchain_build_nios2/gcc-3.4.6/configure --prefix=/opt/nios2 --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu --host=i386-pc-linux-gnu --target=nios2-linux-uclibc --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-target-optspace --with-gnu-ld --disable-shared --disable-nls --enable-threads --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6` I tried with Ubuntu, with Fedora and now I'm going to try with CentOS for compatibility. Last resort will be to download from....

Comment: Dj, where did you get this gcc? (Exact link, please) The problem is not with your host distro, but with nios toolchain / linux source.

Comment: @osgx http://alterawiki.com/wiki/BinaryToolchain It is 3.4.6 in the prebuilt version isn't it?

Comment: What is possible? So far nothing is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to execute NIOS instructions with a i386 processor
Probably because of wrong GCC version

Use the follwoing command to find out which version of GCC is installed, if installed!!

```
      gcc -v
```

Comment: My path is `echo $PATH
/opt/intelFPGA_lite/16.1/quartus//bin:/opt/intelFPGA_lite/16.1/quartus//sopc_builder/bin:/opt/intelFPGA_lite/16.1/nios2eds:/usr/bin:/home/developer/Downloads/NuSMV-2.6.0-Linux/bin/:/home/developer/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/developer/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:/usr/bin:/home/developer/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse:/home/developer/bin:/home/developer/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/developer/Downloads/NuSMV-2.6.0-Linux/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/nios2/bin` so there is something there that overrides?

Comment: I changed my path but I still get the same error `$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/developer/Downloads/NuSMV-2.6.0-Linux/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/nios2/bin`

Comment: @DjDac are you working on an intel processsor? If yes are you using an emulator?

Comment: @DjDac Also what linux are you using? Did you use a virtual machine to run your linux? Please provide more info, And I will tell you what to do

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 (not emulated) with Intel 64-bit (Dell E7450). I looked at the Zephyr project and I wonder which version of Qemu I should install: 64 bit or 32 bit? ANd my target is the Altera DE2-115 which has a Cyclone IV core. I just cloned the Zephyr repo and try to build for Nios II and it says `$ make BOARD=qemu_nios2 qemu
Makefile:607: *** ZEPHYR_GCC_VARIANT is not set. .  Stop`

Comment: Now I have 2 problems. I just wanted to run a simple Linux with my FPGA.

Comment: @DjDac You don't need Qemu, the problem is your GCC version which I am sure is not 4.2 with UBuntu 16.04 , do not try to downgrade GCC cause it will create a mess, I suggest to install ubuntu 9 and install gcc4.2 if you insist to use old version of clinux

Comment: Now I have 3 problems just because I wanted to try simple Linux with a simple FPGA. Ubuntu 9 packages aren't available. VirtualBox can't resize the VM. Now I have 4 problems.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was to replace the named registers with their real names in the assembly file:

```
/*
 * linux/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2009, Wind River Systems Inc
 * Implemented by fredrik.markstrom@gmail.com and ivarholmqvist@gmail.com
 *
 * Based on:
 *
 * linux/arch/nios2/kernel/entry.S  
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1999-2002, Greg Ungerer (gerg@snapgear.com)
 *  Copyright (C) 1998  D. Jeff Dionne <jeff@lineo.ca>,
 *                      Kenneth Albanowski <kjahds@kjahds.com>,
 *  Copyright (C) 2000  Lineo Inc. (www.lineo.com)
 *  Copyright (C) 2004  Microtronix Datacom Ltd.
 *
 * Based on:
 *
 *  linux/arch/m68knommu/kernel/entry.S
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1991, 1992  Linus Torvalds
 *
 * This file is subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public
 * License.  See the file README.legal in the main directory of this archive
 * for more details.
 *
 * Linux/m68k support by Hamish Macdonald
 *
 * 68060 fixes by Jesper Skov
 * ColdFire support by Greg Ungerer (gerg@snapgear.com)
 * 5307 fixes by David W. Miller
 * linux 2.4 support David McCullough <davidm@snapgear.com>
 */

#include <linux/sys.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <asm/asm-offsets.h>
#include <asm/asm-macros.h>
#include <asm/thread_info.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>
#include <asm/setup.h>
#include <asm/entry.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <asm/processor.h>

.macro GET_THREAD_INFO reg
.if THREAD_SIZE & 0xffff0000
    andhi   \reg, sp, %hi(~(THREAD_SIZE-1))
.else
    addi    \reg, r0, %lo(~(THREAD_SIZE-1))
    and \reg, \reg, sp
.endif
.endm

/* FIXME: Lots of these exceptions need to be handled */
.section .rodata
.align 4
exception_table:
    .word unhandled_exception   /* 0 - Reset */
    .word unhandled_exception   /* 1 - Processor-only Reset */
    .word external_interrupt    /* 2 - Interrupt */
    .word handle_trap       /* 3 - Trap Instruction */

    .word instruction_trap      /* 4 - Unimplemented instruction */
    .word handle_illegal        /* 5 - Illegal instruction */
    .word handle_unaligned      /* 6 - Misaligned data access */
    .word handle_unaligned      /* 7 - Misaligned destination address */

    .word handle_diverror       /* 8 - Division error */
    .word protection_exception_ba   /* 9 - Supervisor-only instr. address */
    .word protection_exception_instr /* 10 - Supervisor only instruction */
    .word protection_exception_ba   /* 11 - Supervisor only data address */

    .word unhandled_exception   /* 12 - Double TLB miss (data) */
    .word protection_exception_pte  /* 13 - TLB permission violation (x) */
    .word protection_exception_pte  /* 14 - TLB permission violation (r) */
    .word protection_exception_pte  /* 15 - TLB permission violation (w) */

    .word unhandled_exception   /* 16 - MPU region violation */

trap_table:
    .word   handle_system_call  // 0 
    .word   instruction_trap    // 1
    .word   instruction_trap    // 2
    .word   instruction_trap    // 3
    .word   instruction_trap    // 4
    .word   instruction_trap    // 5
    .word   instruction_trap    // 6
    .word   instruction_trap    // 7
    .word   instruction_trap    // 8
    .word   instruction_trap    // 9
    .word   instruction_trap    // 10
    .word   instruction_trap    // 11
    .word   instruction_trap    // 12
    .word   instruction_trap    // 13
    .word   instruction_trap    // 14
    .word   instruction_trap    // 15
    .word   instruction_trap    // 16
    .word   instruction_trap    // 17
    .word   instruction_trap    // 18
    .word   instruction_trap    // 19
    .word   instruction_trap    // 20
    .word   instruction_trap    // 21
    .word   instruction_trap    // 22
    .word   instruction_trap    // 23
    .word   instruction_trap    // 24
    .word   instruction_trap    // 25
    .word   instruction_trap    // 26
    .word   instruction_trap    // 27
    .word   instruction_trap    // 28
    .word   instruction_trap    // 29
#ifdef CONFIG_KGDB
    .word   handle_kgdb_breakpoint  /* 30 KGDB breakpoint */
#else
    .word   instruction_trap    // 30
#endif
    .word   handle_breakpoint   // 31

.text
.set noat
.set nobreak

ENTRY(inthandler)
    SAVE_ALL
    /* Clear EH bit before we get a new excpetion in the kernel
     * and after we have saved it to the exception frame. This is done
     * wheter it's trap, tlb-miss or interrupt. If we don't do this
     * estatus is not updated the next exception.
     */ 
    rdctl   r24,status
    movi    r9,-5
    and r24,r24,r9
    wrctl   status,r24

    /* Read cause and vector and branch to the associated handler (
         */
    mov r4,sp
        rdctl   r5,ctl7
        movia   r9,exception_table
        add     r24,r9,r5
        ldw     r24,0(r24)
        jmp     r24


/***********************************************************************
 * Handle traps
 ***********************************************************************
 */
ENTRY(handle_trap)
    ldw r24,-4(ea)  // instruction that caused the exception
    srli    r24,r24,4
    andi    r24,r24,0x7c
    movia   r9,trap_table
    add r24,r24,r9
    ldw r24,0(r24)
    jmp r24


/***********************************************************************
 * Handle system calls
 ***********************************************************************
 */
ENTRY(handle_system_call)
    /* Enable interrupts
     */
    rdctl   r10,status      
    ori r10,r10,0x0001
    wrctl   status,r10

    /* Reload registers destroyed by common code.
     */
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)

    /* Check that the requested system call is within limits
     */
    movui   r1,NR_syscalls
    bgeu    r2,r1,ret_invsyscall
    slli    r1,r2,2
    movhi   r11,%hiadj(sys_call_table)
    add r1,r1,r11
    ldw r1,%lo(sys_call_table)(r1)
    beq r1,r0,ret_invsyscall

    /* Get thread info pointer
     */
    movi    r11,%lo(0xfffff000) 
    and r11,sp,r11
    ldw r11,TI_FLAGS(r11)

    /* If someone is ptrace:ing us, take the long way.
     */
    BTBNZ   r11,r11,TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE,traced_system_call
#if 0
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r9,r8
    mov r8,r7
    mov r6,r5
    mov r5,r4
    mov r4,r2
    call    print_syscall
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ldw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)
    ldw r6,PT_R6(sp)
    ldw r7,PT_R7(sp)
    ldw r8,PT_R8(sp)
    ldw r9,PT_R9(sp)
#endif


    /* Execute the system call
     */
    callr   r1

    /* If the syscall returns a negative result:
     *   Set r7 to 1 to indicate error,
     *   Negate r2 to get a positive error code
     * If the syscall returns zero or a positive value:
     *   Set r7 to 0.
     * The sigreturn system calls will skip the code below by
     * adding to register ra. To avoid destroying registers
     * 
     * FIXME: We probably need an orig_r7
     */
translate_rc_and_ret:
    movi    r1,0
    bge r2,zero,3f
    sub r2,zero,r2
    movi    r1,1
3:  
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    stw r1,PT_R7(sp)
end_translate_rc_and_ret:

#if 0
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r4,r2
    mov r5,r1
    call    print_syscall_ret
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
#endif

ret_from_exception:
    ldw r1,PT_ESTATUS(sp)
    TSTBNZ  r1,r1,ESTATUS_EU,Luser_return   /* if so, skip resched, signals */

restore_all:
    rdctl   r10,status          /* disable intrs */
    andi    r10,r10,0xfffe
    wrctl   status, r10
    RESTORE_ALL
    eret

    /* If the syscall number was invalid return ENOSYS
    */
ret_invsyscall:
    movi    r2,-ENOSYS
    br translate_rc_and_ret


    /* This implements the same as above, except it calls
     * syscall_trace before and after the syscall in order
     * for utilities like strace and gdb to work.
     */
traced_system_call:
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    syscall_trace
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK

    /* r2 and r7-r9 might be destroyed  by syscall_trace and we need to restore
     * them before calling our syscall.
     */
    ldw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)
    ldw r6,PT_R6(sp)
    ldw r7,PT_R7(sp)
    ldw r8,PT_R8(sp)
    ldw r9,PT_R9(sp)

    /* Fetch the syscall function, we don't need to check the boundaries
     * since this is already done.
     */
    slli    r1,r2,2
    movhi   r11,%hiadj(sys_call_table)
    add r1,r1,r11
    ldw r1,%lo(sys_call_table)(r1)

    callr   r1

    /* If the syscall returns a negative result:
     *   Set r7 to 1 to indicate error,
     *   Negate r2 to get a positive error code
     * If the syscall returns zero or a positive value:
     *   Set r7 to 0.
     * The sigreturn system calls will skip the code below by
     * adding to register ra. To avoid destroying registers
     * 
     * FIXME: We probably need an orig_r7
     */
translate_rc_and_ret2:
    movi    r1,0
    bge r2,zero,4f
    sub r2,zero,r2
    movi    r1,1
4:  
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    stw r1,PT_R7(sp)
end_translate_rc_and_ret2:
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    syscall_trace
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    br ret_from_exception

Luser_return:
    GET_THREAD_INFO r11         /* get thread_info pointer */
    ldw r10,TI_FLAGS(r11)       /* get thread_info->flags */
    ANDI32  r11,r10,_TIF_WORK_MASK
    beq r11,r0,restore_all      /* Nothing to do */
    BTBZ    r1,r10,TIF_NEED_RESCHED,Lsignal_return

Lwork_resched:
    call    schedule
    br  ret_from_exception

Lsignal_return:
    BTBZ    r1,r10,TIF_SIGPENDING,restore_all
    mov r5,sp           /* pt_regs */
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r4,r0           /* oldset = 0 */
    movi    r6,1            /* syscall */
    call    do_signal
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    br  restore_all



/***********************************************************************
 * Handle external interrupts.
 ***********************************************************************
 */
/*
 * This is the generic interrupt handler (for all hardware interrupt
 * sources). It figures out the vector number and calls the appropriate
 * interrupt service routine directly.
 */
external_interrupt:
    rdctl   r12,ipending
    rdctl   r9,ienable
    and r12,r12,r9
    /* skip if no interrupt is pending */
    beq r12,r0,ret_from_interrupt

    movi    r24,-1
    stw r24,PT_ORIG_R2(sp)

    /*
     * Process an external hardware interrupt.
     */

    addi    ea,ea,-4        /* re-issue the interrupted instruction */
    stw ea,PT_EA(sp)
2:  movi    r4,%lo(-1)      /* Start from bit position 0, highest priority */
                    /* This is the IRQ # for handler call */
1:  andi    r10,r12,1       /* Isolate bit we are interested in */
    srli    r12,r12,1       /* shift count is costly without hardware multiplier */
    addi    r4,r4,1
    beq r10,r0,1b
    mov r5,sp           /* Setup pt_regs pointer for handler call */
    call    do_IRQ
    rdctl   r12,ipending        /* check again if irq still pending */
    rdctl   r9,ienable      /* Isolate possible interrupts */
    and r12,r12,r9
    bne r12,r0,2b
    /* br   ret_from_interrupt */   /* fall throught to ret_from_interrupt */

ENTRY(ret_from_interrupt)
    ldw r1,PT_ESTATUS(sp)   /* check if returning to kernel */
    TSTBNZ  r1,r1,ESTATUS_EU,Luser_return

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT
    GET_THREAD_INFO r1
    ldw r4,TI_PREEMPT_COUNT(r1)
    bne r4,r0,restore_all

need_resched:
    ldw r4,TI_FLAGS(r1)     // ? Need resched set
    BTBZ    r10,r4,TIF_NEED_RESCHED,restore_all
    ldw r4,PT_ESTATUS(sp)   // ? Interrupts off
    andi    r10,r4,STATUS_PIE
    beq r10,r0,restore_all
    movia   r4,PREEMPT_ACTIVE
    stw r4,TI_PREEMPT_COUNT(r1)
    rdctl   r10,status      /* enable intrs again */
    ori r10,r10,0x0001
    wrctl   status,r10
    PUSH    r1
    call    schedule
    POP r1
    mov r4,r0
    stw r4,TI_PREEMPT_COUNT(r1)
    rdctl   r10,status      /* disable intrs */
    andi    r10,r10,0xfffe
    wrctl   status, r10
    br  need_resched
#else
    br  restore_all
#endif

/***********************************************************************
 * Syscalls implemented in assembly
 ***********************************************************************
 */

ENTRY(sys_nios2cmpxchg)

    // r4 pointer to exchange variable
    // r5 old value
    // r6 new value
    // r8 - old interrupt status (assert this to enabled?)
    // r9 - temp
    // Disable interrupts (keep old status in r8)
        rdctl   r8,status
        andi    r9,r8,0xfffe
        wrctl   status,r9

    // Make sure we skip the r2/r7 translation code when we return.
        addi    ra,ra,(end_translate_rc_and_ret-translate_rc_and_ret)

ldw1:   ldw     r2, 0(r4)
        bne     r2, r5, .L6

    // We had a match, store the new value
stw1:   stw     r6, 0(r4)
.L6:
    // Reenable interrupts
        wrctl   status,r8

    // Store return value
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    // Indicate everything is ok
    movi    r2,0
    stw r2,PT_R7(sp)
        ret
fault:
        movi    r2,EFAULT
    stw r2,PT_R2(sp)
    movi    r2,1
    stw r2,PT_R7(sp)
        wrctl   status,r8
        ret

    // setup the exception table
    .section __ex_table,"a"
        .word ldw1, fault
    .word stw1, fault
        .previous



/***********************************************************************
 * A few syscall wrappers
 ***********************************************************************
 */

ENTRY(sys_fork)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_fork
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_vfork)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_vfork
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_execve)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_execve
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_clone)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    nios2_clone
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_sigsuspend)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_sigsuspend
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_rt_sigsuspend)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_rt_sigsuspend
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_sigreturn)
    mov r4,sp
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_sigreturn
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    addi    ra,ra,(end_translate_rc_and_ret-translate_rc_and_ret)
    ret

ENTRY(sys_sigaltstack)
    ldw r4,PT_R4(sp)
    ldw r5,PT_R5(sp)
    ldw r6,PT_SP(sp)
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call    do_sigaltstack
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    ret

ENTRY(sys_rt_sigreturn)
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    mov r4,sp
    call    do_rt_sigreturn
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    addi    ra,ra,(end_translate_rc_and_ret-translate_rc_and_ret)
    ret

/***********************************************************************
 * A few other wrappers and stubs
 ***********************************************************************
 */
protection_exception_pte:
    rdctl r6,pteaddr
    slli r6,r6,10
    call do_page_fault
    br ret_from_exception

protection_exception_ba:
    rdctl r6,ctl12
    call do_page_fault
    br ret_from_exception

protection_exception_instr:
    call handle_supervisor_instr
    br ret_from_exception

handle_breakpoint:
    call breakpoint_c
    br ret_from_exception

#ifdef CONFIG_ALIGNMENT_TRAP
handle_unaligned:
    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    call handle_unaligned_c
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK
    br ret_from_exception
#else
handle_unaligned:
    call handle_unaligned_c
    br ret_from_exception
#endif

handle_illegal:
    call handle_illegal_c
    br ret_from_exception

handle_diverror:
    call handle_diverror_c
    br ret_from_exception

#ifdef CONFIG_KGDB
handle_kgdb_breakpoint:
    call kgdb_breakpoint_c
    br ret_from_exception
#endif

/*
 * Beware - when entering resume, prev (the current task) is
 * in r4, next (the new task) is in r5, don't change these
 * registers.
 */
ENTRY(resume)

    rdctl   r7,status           /* save thread status reg */
    stw r7,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KPSR(r4)  

    andi    r7,r7,0x0fffe           /* disable interrupts */
    wrctl   status,r7

    SAVE_SWITCH_STACK
    stw sp,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KSP(r4)   /* save kernel stack pointer */
    ldw sp,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KSP(r5)   /* restore new thread stack */
    movia   r24,_current_thread     /* save thread */
    GET_THREAD_INFO r1
    stw r1,0(r24)
    RESTORE_SWITCH_STACK

    ldw r7,TASK_THREAD+THREAD_KPSR(r5)  /* restore thread status reg */
    wrctl   status,r7
    ret

ENTRY(ret_from_fork)
    call    schedule_tail
    br  ret_from_exception
```